# Provide progress on data processing

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, stream

I've written a Node package that performs some intensive data processing. I'm able to watch progress via `console.log`, but I'd like to provide the end user with some way of monitoring it in an event-driven way. Basically, it would be like returning a promise, except instead of one `then` event it would have an event for each "step", and then finally resolve with the data.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Node streams (which I'm guessing is the thing I need) to do this. Can I get a few pointers? How can I create a stream which is updated every time there is, say, 1% more progress, and then finally gives the computed data?

EDIT: As an example, consider this loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    intensiveFunction();
    console.log(`${i} of ${N} completed`);
}
```

What I want to do instead is

```
for(let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    intensiveFunction();
    // send user a signal that i/N of the task has been completed
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more info. What are you processing? Progress on a file read for example? Or what kind of processing are you talking about.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use streams, You can use an [EventEmitter](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_eventname_args), and emit the current progress, or any event you may want.

**my-package.js**

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');

// Create a class that extends from EventEmitter
// And now you can emit events when something happens, e.g., progress update
class MyPackage extends EventEmitter {

    async intensiveFunction() {
        // Something
    }

    async process() {

        for(let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            await this.intensiveFunction();
            this.emit('step', i, N); // Or send progress in % or whatever you want
        }
    }
}


module.exports = MyPackage;
```

**index.js**

```
const MyPackage = require('my-package');

const package = new MyPackage();

package.on('step', (step, total) => console.log(`${step}/${total}`));
package.process();
```

You can either provide a full events API, or mix it with promises. Meaning `process` can resolve once is done, or you can emit an `end` event, or do both.

```
async process() {

   for(let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
      await this.intensiveFunction();
      this.emit('step', i, N); // Or send progress in % or whatever you want
   }

   // Emit the end event
   this.emit('end', result);       

   // And resolve the promise
   return result; // Whatever result is
}
```